# How can I dump the normal properties on an IEnumerable in Linqpad

Tags: ienumerable, dump, linqpad

If I have an object that among other things is an IEnumerable and I dump this object I get the enumerated values.

Is there a way to get Linqpad to list the other properties:

Se example below:
Can I get Dump to include Hello and digits properties?

```
void Main()
{
    var t = new test();
    var d = new Dictionary<string,string> {{"Hello","World"},{"Good by","Sky"}};

    t.Dump();
    d.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class test : IEnumerable
{
    public string Hello { get { return "World"; }}
    public List<int> digits { get { return new List<int> {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; }}

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() { yield return "Hej"; }
}
```

Comment: nothing liek a speedy answer - you need to add your own ToDump() method to the object. See https://www.linqpad.net/CustomizingDump.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell if the object you're trying to dump implements `IEnumerable` then LINQPad always wants to dump it as an IEnumerable list.  Getting rid of the interface correctly shows the `Hello` and `digits` properties in the dumped info.

Going from [this link](http://www.linqpad.net/HowLINQPadWorks.aspx) it appears you can write your own dump which accomplishes something like LINQPad by enumerating the collection *and* all it's properties then outputting the whole thing as an XHTML string.  I haven't tried this.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer as it explained the reason why Dump acts as it does. I was primarily looking if there was a setting or parameter I could use.

Answer (score 6):

You could write a **DumpPayload** extension method as follows:

```
void Main()
{
    var t = new test();
    t.DumpPayload();
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void DumpPayload (this IEnumerable o)
    {
        if (o == null)
        {
            o.Dump();
            return;
        }
        var d = new Dictionary<string,object>();        
        foreach (var member in o.GetType().GetProperties())
            try
            {
                d[member.Name] = member.GetValue (o, null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                d[member.Name] = ex;
            }           
        d["AsEnumerable"] = o;
        d.Dump();
    }   
}
```

If you put this extension method into "My Extensions", it will be available to all queries.

Another solution is to implement ICustomMemberProvider in the test class:

```
public class test : IEnumerable, ICustomMemberProvider
{
    public string Hello { get { return "World"; }}
    public List<int> digits { get { return new List<int> {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; }}

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() { yield return "Hej"; }

    IEnumerable<string> ICustomMemberProvider.GetNames() 
    {
        return "Hello Enumerator".Split();
    }

    IEnumerable<Type> ICustomMemberProvider.GetTypes ()
    {
        return new [] { typeof (string), typeof (IEnumerable) };
    }

    IEnumerable<object> ICustomMemberProvider.GetValues ()
    {
        return new object [] { Hello, this.OfType<Object>() };
    }   
}
```

Note that if the test class is defined in another assembly, you don't need to reference LINQPad in order to implement [ICustomMemberProvider](http://www.linqpad.net/FAQ.aspx#extensibility). You can just paste in the following definition into your project and LINQPad will pick it up:

```
namespace LINQPad
{
   public interface ICustomMemberProvider
   {
      IEnumerable<string> GetNames ();
      IEnumerable<Type> GetTypes ();
      IEnumerable<object> GetValues ();
   }
}
```

Comment: This answer deserves way more upvotes, ICustomMemberProvider helped me when I had a custom type that was ICollection<self> (where self is that type) for recursive data and subclasses which inherited from that custom type. Now my structure dumps correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Use a Serializer?

Json.NET will do all of this for you in a json format.

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented)

if you don't want json, then pick a serializer you do want, or you'll just have to do what a serializer would do, use reflection to iterate the properties on the object.