# How to .Dump() XNode as a regular object with properties in LINQPad?

Tags: linqpad

Normally, the `.Dump()` extension method in LINQPad shows `XNode` and its derived class instances as a rendered XML fragment. Sometimes while developing code I would prefer to see actual properties of the object, in the same table form that is dumped for other types, like a table that would show the Name, Value, FirstAttribute and whatsnot properties of the node and their `.ToString()` values, or interactively expandable collections of subobjects. In short, as if XNode were not handled specially at all.

I am working around this by dumping individual properties, but this is tedious.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4002404/1149924) suggests writing a custom extension code to achieve a similar effect for another type, namely IEnumerable, but it seems a narrower and rarer case than that which I am dealing with.

Is there an out-of-the box way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

LINQPad supports customizing `Dump` for types. Using some extension methods, you can convert the types to `ExpandoObject`s and then they will be output with properties.

In My Extensions, after the `MyExtensions` class, add a top level method:

```
static object ToDump(object obj) {
    if (obj is XObject x)
        return x.ToExpando();
    else
        return obj;
}
```

In the `MyExtensions` class, add the following extension methods. I already had the `object`->`Dictionary` methods for converting to anonymous objects, so I used those, but you could combine them to create a single `ToExpando` on `object`:

```
public static ExpandoObject ToExpando(this object obj) => obj.ToDictionary().ToExpando();

public static IDictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(this object obj) {
    if (obj is IDictionary<string, object> id)
        return id;
    else {
        var dictAnsObj = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetPropertiesOrFields()) {
            try {
                dictAnsObj.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(obj));
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                dictAnsObj.Add(prop.Name, ex);
            }
        }

        return dictAnsObj;
    }
}

public static ExpandoObject ToExpando(this IDictionary<string, object> objDict) {
    var e = new ExpandoObject();
    var di = (IDictionary<string, object>)e;

    foreach (var kvp in objDict)
        di.Add(kvp);

    return e;
}
```

You will also need this `Type` extension:

```
// ***
// *** Type Extensions
// ***
public static List<MemberInfo> GetPropertiesOrFields(this Type t, BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) =>
    t.GetMembers(bf).Where(mi => mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field | mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property).ToList();
```

If you are okay with just displaying the top level object in class format, you could just use this extension method when you need to:

```
public static T DumpAs<T, NewT>(this T obj, Func<T, NewT> castFn, string description = null) {
    if (description != null)
        castFn(obj).Dump(description);
    else
        castFn(obj).Dump();

    return obj;
}
```

For example,

```
XElement xn;
xn.DumpAs(x => x.ToExpando());
```

Otherwise, you will have to comment out the `ToDump` method or do something tricky with fluent methods to turn it on and off.

Answer (score 0):

This answer depends on the previous answer, but extends it to handle dumping `XObject`s as classes when desired with an alternative extension method and `ToDump` method. It uses the same extensions as my previous answer otherwise.

In the `MyExtensions` class, add a new type of dump and a `bool` to track status:

```
public static bool bDumpAsClass = false;

public static object DumpAsClass(this object input, string descr = null) {
    bDumpAsClass = true;
    if (descr != null)
        input.Dump(descr);
    else
        input.Dump();
    bDumpAsClass = false;
    return input;
}
```

Outside the `MyExtensions` class, add a `ToDump` method that uses the `bool`:

```
static object ToDump(object obj) {
    if (MyExtensions.bDumpAsClass) {
        if (obj is XObject x)
            return x.ToExpando();
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Then you can just use `DumpAsClass` instead of `Dump` when you want to dump an `XObject` or descendant as a class, expanding any members as well.

Obviously you could expand the types handled when `bDumpAsClass` is true.